# Why does a call to my List<Point>.Clear() throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, list, exception

I have a `List<Point>` that is supposed to be cleared often, as the values are used once per iteration, and I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` while invoking the `Clear()` method.

I read a explanation that deals with multi-threading, but as far as I'm aware I've created no threads (unless c# automates for or while loops into threads somehow, but I doubt that).

Here is my code:

```
List<Point> temp = new List<Point>();
List<Point> visited = new List<Point>();
// other initializations
for(int i = 0; i < points.Count;i++){
    if(temp.Count != 0)
        temp.Clear(); // Problem occurs here
    temp.Add(A);
    temp.Add(B);
    temp.Add(C);
    temp.Add(D);
    while(!(visited.Contains(temp[0]) && visited.Contains(temp[1])...){
        // calculate some stuff
        for(int j = 0; j <4;j++)
            visited.Add(temp[j]);
        // use point of interests
        temp.Clear();  // no issue on this clear
        temp.Add(newA);
        temp.Add(newB);
        temp.Add(newC);
        temp.Add(newD);
    }
    // display results
}
```

It throws the ArgumentOutOfRangeException from the first `temp.Clear()` call.

I've also noticed that if I clear the visited list in the same position as the problem `temp.Clear()`, I get the same error.

To me it seems like a problem that is c# specific, and as I'm very new to the language I'm wondering if I'm not understanding something.

Comment: If you don't mind, do a full clean/rebuild of your project. If you haven't somehow overridden Clear(), that exception is not likely from that line of code. It's possible the debugger is lying to you - I've seen it in some projects.

Comment: Can you rejig this as a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem? What *exactly* is the exception? (Can you post the full stack trace?)

Comment: it is a runtime error, it is the System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:Index was out of range error

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: There's no way that line there would cause an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for the types you have shown us... either the exception is coming from something else or you're not actually telling us the actual types.  Show us the actual code and the more info about the exception.

Comment: @CynicalOptimist: But please post the full stack trace, not just the message.

Comment: It occurs when I add that line of code, which is why I am saying it is the problem area, thanks for the responses

Comment: Are you building Debug or Release?

Comment: There's a difference between adding a line of code and that same new line of code being where an error occurred - if you step through the code line by line does it occur on the Clear call?

Comment: Show us your entire method, since this does not demonstrate the problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your exception is when you try to access your `temp` items, List.Clear() doesn't throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because implements first [IList.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.clear%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and finally [ICollection.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5axy4fbh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and they just throw `NotSupportedException` from .net2 till now not `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, If you call your method in different threads I guess your problem is within this lines:

```
    while(!(visited.Contains(temp[0]) && visted.Contains(temp[1])...){
    //calculate some stuff
    for(int j = 0; j <4;j++)
        visited.Add(temp[j]);
```

and you can solve it by surrounding this part in [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) block.

Also it's better to use `visited.Intersect(temp).Count ==0` instead of your long `if` condition.

**Edit:** By your updated question problem is clear:

## while(... (current != points[i + 1])) ooopps

when i = n - 1, `points[i + 1]` is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in front of VS, however, instead of:

```
temp.Clear();
```

could you try:

```
temp = new List<Point>();
```

Here's some sample code I have **threw** together and it runs fine for me:

```
        public void TestPoints()
        {
            List<Point> temp = new List<Point>();
            List<Point> visited = new List<Point>();
            List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
            points.Add(new Point(100, 100));
            points.Add(GeneratePoint());
            points.Add(GeneratePoint());
            points.Add(GeneratePoint());
            points.Add(GeneratePoint());


            //other initialization
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
            {
                if (temp.Count != 0)
                    temp.Clear(); //Problem occurs here
                temp.Add(GeneratePoint());
                temp.Add(GeneratePoint());
                temp.Add(GeneratePoint());
                temp.Add(GeneratePoint());
                while (!(visited.Contains(temp[0]) && visited.Contains(temp[1])))
                {
                    //calculate some stuff
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                        visited.Add(temp[j]);
                    //use point of interests
                    temp.Clear(); //no issue on this clear
                    temp.Add(GeneratePoint());
                    temp.Add(GeneratePoint());
                    temp.Add(GeneratePoint());
                    temp.Add(GeneratePoint());
                }
                //display results
            }
        }
        public Point GeneratePoint()
        {
            return new Point((new Random()).Next(1, 100), (new Random()).Next(1, 100));
        }
```

As other have suggested, have you tried to 'Clean' and 'Rebuild' your solution.

What version of .NET? It's not Mono by any chance is it?

Comment: You mean that `new` threw the exception?

Comment: Are you building Debug or Release?

Comment: well my code depends on a lot of behind the scenes frame work

Comment: I did clean/Rebuild with no improvement(not sure what it does)

Comment: Ok, can we have some more information, either additional code or as Jon Skeet mentioned, the stacktrace information.

Answer (score 1):

Im inclined to believe you debugger may be out of synch as other posts have mentioned

if that is the case im inclined to believe that the error is on the only line that you haven't given us in full:

```
while(!(visited.Contains(temp[0]) && visited.Contains(temp[1])...){
```

does it access `temp[0] ... temp[3]` or `temp[0] ... temp[4]`

Comment: it accesses temp[0] through temp[3]

Answer (score 1):

Note: As Answer rather than Comment just because this is wordy - this *doesn't* contain the solution to the problem

OK, having decompiled the generic List Clear method, it looks like this:

```
public void Clear()
{
    if (this._size > 0)
    {
        Array.Clear(this._items, 0, this._size);
        this._size = 0;
    }
    List`1 list`1s = this;
    list`1s._version = list`1s._version + 1;
}
```

This is *potentially* not thread safe (if this._size changes from the "if" condition to the `Array.Clear` line then you can have an issue).  `Array.Clear` will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception if you provide invalid arguments.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx

However, there is *no way* that `List<T>.Clear` can be that frail - so plausible answers include: something in your code is either playing with threads or its not that line

So as a way forward can you step through the code and confirm its the `Clear()` invocation that is raising the error - ie show the stack trace

Comment: Very helpful comment thank you very much led me to the solution, but I believe it really was along the line of dice's proposal, I was accessing point outside of the points array, although I would think that for(int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++) would stay within the array.

Comment: Thanks.  Note that your "for" loop statement does stay within the array but the line that @dice points out tries to go beyond it.  That's why its important to find out which line is causing the problem - ArgumentOutOfRangeException is clear and correct - you were trying to go beyond the range of the array.

Answer (score 1):

`points[i+1]` looks wrong in that `while` loop (in the `if()`). Your loop goes to `points.Count` which is 1 greater than the greatest index. Hitting that would be an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. (Unless I'm overlooking something.)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem today while clearing ObservableCollection, synchrounously, on button click. This is my workaround, though I would be grateful if someone shared some more information about this.

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> collection)
{
    while (collection.Count > 0)
    {
        if (collection.Count == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                collection.RemoveAt(collection.Count - 1);
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                if (collection.Count > 0)
                    throw;
            }
        }
        else
            collection.RemoveAt(collection.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

//EDIT

Ok now Count thrown the same exception so I decided to dig deeper and found:

```
   w System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   w Infragistics.FastItemDateTimeColumn.get_Item(Int32 index)
   w Infragistics.Controls.Charts.OrdinalTimeXAxis.UpdateActualRange()
   w Infragistics.Controls.Charts.OrdinalTimeXAxis.UpdateRangeOverride()
   w Infragistics.Controls.Charts.Axis.UpdateRange(Boolean immediate)
   w Infragistics.Controls.Charts.OrdinalTimeXAxis.OnFastItemsSourceEvent(FastItemsSourceEventArgs e)
   w Infragistics.Controls.Charts.CategoryAxisBase.HandleFastItemsSourceEvent(Object sender, FastItemsSourceEventArgs e)
   w System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   w Infragistics.FastItemsSource.RaiseDataSourceEvent(FastItemsSourceEventAction action, Int32 position, Int32 count)
   w Infragistics.FastItemsSource.dataSourceRemove(Int32 position, IList oldItems)
   w Infragistics.FastItemsSource.OnItemsSourceEventProxyWeakCollectionChanged(IFastItemsSource fastItemsSource, Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   w Infragistics.FastItemsSource.<Attach>b__16_0(IFastItemsSource fastItemsSource, Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   w Infragistics.ItemSourceEventProxy.collectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   w System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   w System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   w System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.RemoveItem(Int32 index)
   w System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
   w CryptoBot.Source.Common.Extensions.Extensions.RemoveAll[T](IList`1 collection) w G:\Moje Pliki\Programowanie\CSharp\Projects\CryptoBot\Cryptobot\CryptoBot\Source\Common\Extensions\Extensions.cs:wiersz 1035
```

So in similar scenarios Collection is most likely bound to something that is using some async calls inside. Whether you have access to it or not.